# FileNotFoundException is thrown at method call without entering method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So I'm running into a truly perplexing FileNotFoundException that I am unsure how to troubleshoot.

I have the a .cs file that serves as a basic template for web page methods. In it, I have the following private method:

```
private void Initialize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some initialize functions and...

        AddWebAnalyticsScript();
    }
```

`AddWebAnalyticsScript()` is a private function in the same class. It handles the loading of some Google Web Analytics code. Debugging through this class, I saw that AddWebAnalyticsScript() was throwing a FileNotFoundException for a dependent assembly.

I tried placing breakpoints within the function definition, because I assumed some logic in there was referencing the missing assembly. However when I placed breakpoints within the function definition, I found that this exception is thrown BEFORE any code is executed in the function; it happens immediately upon the call. I've never seen this happen before and I can't find any documentation on similar issues. Conceptually I don't understand why a CALL to a function defined in the same class would be looking for an assembly, until contained code is actually executed.

Additionally, the assembly seems to appear under References exactly where it should be.

So I'm mystified. Beyond placing breakpoints within the function definition, I can't think of how else to troubleshoot. Using the debugger 'step into' action on the AddWebAnalyticsScript(); causes the exception to be immediately thrown.

Error text;

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'myApplication.Frameworks.WebAnalyticsInterface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0113ab8eb0779932' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"myApplication.Frameworks.WebAnalyticsInterface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0113ab8eb0779932"}
```

Stack trace:

```
at MyApplication.PageTemplate.AddWebAnalyticsScript()
at MyApplication.PageTemplate.Initialize(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\\{filepath}:line 246
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.UserControl.OnInit(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

From fusion log:

```
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\MyApp\Web\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: MyApp.Frameworks.WebAnalyticsInterface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0113ab8eb0779932
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check (hr = 0x80070002).
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the stack trace of the exception. The types used in `AddWebAnalyticsScript()` are loaded when you first call it; perhaps there's a static constructor somewhere that tries to access some files.

Comment: Add the error and the StackTrace if you want help...

Comment: You found that dependent assembly was missing right? Then what's the problem in adding it back?

Comment: Added stacktrace. And no, the dependent assembly seems to be there. But also I'm trying to figure out why it would even be referenced in this case, because I think (ideally) it shouldn't be blowing up if nothing is using it / calling members.

Comment: +1 to codecaster comment. Also, there is an option in visual studio to break when an exception is thrown. it is under Debug->Exeptions. try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you state yourself there is no way that a method you defined would need call to an external assembly before code is executed inside the method.

You also mentioned that the offending assembly is actually referenced directly. This doesn't necessarily mean that all dependant assemblies to that assembly can be located.

In order to solve dll loading issues, always use [Fusion Logging](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx). The article I referenced contains information about how to turn it on and use it. It is really simple.

There could be a lot of reasons why an assembly cannot be loaded including exception on a bad image format(x64 vs x86), wrong search path, etc. These can all be differentiated with the Fusion Log as it logs all attemps in different paths and gives details why a certain assembly failed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Added the excerpt from the Fusion log. I'm not really sure as to the implications of those errors and there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation. Are there more robust logs for the actual errors? `ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check.` is fairly vague.

Comment: @Proton please try to search the web and this site for how to use Fusion logging. The _"The same bind was seen before"_ error indicates you haven't recycled your application pool. When you do, you get a full log _you_ can read through.